# Matching entries in arrays powershell

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, search

I have two data sets one is a data table pulled back from a SQL date base and the other is a data set pulled back from Active directory

```
$HRusers = Invoke-SQL ## this calls a function to get data from SQL
$adusers = get-aduser -filter * -Properties surname,EmployeeID,DisplayName
```

I want to then match the two together so my code at the moment is

```
    $HRusers | ForEach-Object {

    foreach ($user in $aduser){

     if ((($_.Surname -eq $user.surname) -And ($_.'First Name' -eq $user.Givenname)) -or (($_.Surname -eq $user.surname) -And ($_.'Known As' -eq $user.Givenname))) 
{ do some stuff}

    }
    }
```

This does work but as the list for each is several 1000 long it is a lot of looping.

is there any way I can do a search rather than a loop. so the logic is more like

$HRusers | ForEach-Object {

find match in AD list where name matchs and then do some stuff.

}

EDIT

So I tried this

```
if  (($adusers.surname -eq $_.surname) -And ($adusers.Givenname -eq $_.'First Name'))
 {
 write-host "Found" $adusers.surname
 }
```

Which does give a true / false answer, but i need to extract the $aduser record that it giving the match.

Looking on technet

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692798.aspx
"note that, with –like, you get back the actual values rather than a Boolean True or False"

So I expected

```
   $users = ($adusers.Givenname -like ($_.'First Name') -and $adusers.surname -like ($_.'surname'))


 write-host $users
```

to return the value but it still only returns true / false?

Answer (score 0):

You can search the array with `where-object`:

```
foreach ($hruser in $hrusers) {
    $adusers | where-object {$hruser.'First Name' -eq $_.givenname} | ForEach-Object {
        'do some stuff'
    }
}
```

Or use the fact that `Invoke-SqlCmd` returns `DataTable` which has `Select` method:

```
foreach ($aduser in $adusers){
    $SelectedHrUsers = $hrusers.Select("surname='$($aduser.surname)'")
}
```

The former won't be much faster that nested arrays, but `DataTable.Select` might have good performance.